# SQL Developer script output: language english + utf-8 characters ('ő', 'ű')

Tags: oracle, plsql, utf-8, oracle-sqldeveloper

How can I set in SQL developer script output language english, but with non-english, special characters appears ('ő', 'ű').

I think it is an encoding question. I set the utf-8 encoding and it works properly in query result (e.g. the result of select from table shows the character 'őűö'), but in the script output appears '?' instead of 'ő' (e.g. in dbms_serveroutput.put_line, or raise_application_error message). H

E.g.

```
select * from test;

A
---
űőö
```

(it's okay)

```
declare
    char varchar2(20);
begin
    select * into char from test;
    dbms_output.put_line(char);
end;
/



??ö

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed
```

(??ö instead of űőö)

My settings:

```
PARAMETER   VALUE
NLS_RDBMS_VERSION   12.2.0.1.0
NLS_NCHAR_CHARACTERSET  AL16UTF16
NLS_CHARACTERSET    AL32UTF8
NLS_LANGUAGE    AMERICAN
```

SQL Developer:
Tools - Preferences - Environment - Encoding: UTF-8

Regedit:
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\ORACLE\KEY_OraDB12Home1
NLS_LANG: AMERICAN_UNITED KINGDOM.AL32UTF8

(SQL developer version 18.1.0.095)

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

```
select unistr( '\0169\00f5\00f6' ) from dual;

UNI
---
ũõö


declare 
    c varchar2(20);
begin
    select unistr( '\0169\00f5\00f6' ) into c from dual;
    dbms_output.put_line( c );
end;
/

UNI
---
ũõö
```

And I'm using the same version of SQLDev and a AL32UTF8 database. What's the definition of your `test` table?

Comment: create table test (A varchar2(20)); insert into test values ('űőö'); but the solution is a simple restart

Answer (score 0):

The key is preferences - encoding settings in SQL developer but not enough to change the settings. A RESTART is neccessary as well.

Steps and results:

> 1. tools - preferences - environment - encoding = ASCII
> 2. restart

```
begin dbms_output.put_line('űőö'); end;
/

-- result: '???'
```

> 3. tools - preferences - environment - encoding = UTF-8

```
begin dbms_output.put_line('űőö'); end;
/

-- result: '???'
```

> 4. RESTART sqldeveloper

```
begin dbms_output.put_line('űőö'); end;
/

-- result: 'űőö''
```